# Need help with a fluid layout

Tags: css, tabs, fluid

I have a semi-fluid layout that is causing me a few issues. It's getting very close, but a couple of elements are being pushed down when I contract the window. You can see it here:

http://dev.tdcdesign.com/osms/sales_reps/

When I shrink the window, the tabs for the table navigation (mid way down the page) are pushing down, as well as the calendar key (to the direct left of the calendar). How can I get these elements to behave properly? I can't seem to make it work no matter what I do, and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Thats a common behavior - where else should those elements stay on small screens? But if you really want them in one line, give a try to `white-space: nowrap;` for the surrounding element.

Comment: I got the calendar key, it was because it was bumping up against the div that contained all the rep information on the left, so I shorted it. Still having issues with the tab nav, however, and the nowrap attribute does not seem to have any effect on the ul container

Comment: "the nowrap attribute does not seem to have any effect on the ul container" Yes it does, if you replace the `float: left;` by `display: inline-block;` for the inner `LI`s. But if they are lined up, they will overflow to the right…

Comment: That does work, but the ul then overlaps the side of the container when I shrink. If I just set a min-width on the .ui-tabs, though, it seems to work, which I'm guessing will be required no matter how it is configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the ul container to `white-space:nowrap` and set a min-width on the .ui-tabs, seems to be working properly now.